# problem installing chromium

Tags: software-installation, chromium

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and because I want to use my Chromecast I think I'll need Chrome or Chromium.

The the software-center ("store") doesn't launch.

So I pasted the line `sudo apt-get install chromium` in the terminal and entered my password.

```
chromium-bsu:i386 chromium-bsu
```

I obtained the following text:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  chromium-bsu:i386 chromium-bsu

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  chromium-bsu:i386 chromium-bsu
E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate
```

So I pasted `chromium-bsu:i386 chromium-bsu`

but got this answer:

```
chromium-bsu:i386: command not found
```

What now?

I also downloaded the installation file of Chrome,

```
google-chrome-42-0-2311-90-32-bit-multi-ubu.deb
```

but nothing happens when I double-click it

I was a Windows user, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: You seem to have a very old version of a Chrome installation file (version 42). Chrome is currently version 62, you download a newer version from: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/features.html

Answer (score 7):

Chromium web browser (*chromium-browser*) is an open-source version of Google Chrome. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

To install the Chrome .deb file that you downloaded change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains google-chrome-42-0-2311-90-32-bit-multi-ubu.deb and run the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-42-0-2311-90-32-bit-multi-ubu.deb
```

`dpkg -i` suggested by Cynplytholowazy also installs the same Chrome .deb file, but it doesn't do any automatic dependency resolution as the above command, which uses `apt` instead of `dpkg`, does.

Comment: You can also install it as a snap: `sudo snap install chromium`

Answer (score 5):

Don't paste `chromium-bsu:i386` unless you have `i386` architecture enabled. `chromium-bsu:i386` is the 32-bit version of `chromium-bsu` package.

Note that `chromium-bsu` is a game though, you should install `chromium-browser` instead.

Simply just type:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

and you will get Chromium installed. Note that it is 64-bit.

As for the installation of Google Chrome, you can install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-42-0-2311-90-32-bit-multi-ubu.deb
```

Assuming you have your installation file in the folder `/home/(user)/Downloads`.

Comment: This command is wrong this is for a game called `chromium-bsu/xenial 0.9.15.1-1 amd64
  fast paced, arcade-style, scrolling space shooter` Please delete this answer

Comment: I got additional information regarding his issue of not doing anything when clicking `.deb` installation file. Thanks for reminding me that `chromium-bsu` is a game. I did the same wrong thing before as well.